# reading data from an excel sheet in perl

Tags: excel, perl, file-io, cpan

I have a hash of result messages. Each message has 4-5 different parameters. I want to match parameter values with the values stored in an excel sheet. If they match its pass or fail
Can you help me how to read from an excel sheet and match it line by line with my current message in hash.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to read from an Excel file is using a CPAN module, like [Spreadsheet::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet%3a%3aXLSX)

Comment: Can you help me with cpan modules..I have no idea how to use them in my script.Basic steps would be appreciated

Comment: http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html, cpan is a great repository of very helpful modules

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS Excel 2003 or earlier, you can use - [ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.59/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm)

If you are using excel 2007 or higher (xlsx), then Spreadsheet::XLSX does the job.

If you want something very quick and simple try - [Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~tmtm/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-Simple-1.04/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel/Simple.pm) Its an easy to use wrapper around ParseExcel.